# Paperclip not applying crop processor to original image (i.e. can't recrop a cropped photo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Im using jCrop with Rails 3.2.14 to crop images following the ever popular Railscast from Ryan  - http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images.

This works 100%, EXCEPT when I try to crop a photo that I already cropped.  The problem appears to be that the paperclip processors only apply the processing to the original image but do NOT convert that original image, so when I try to recrop a cropped image it's trying to crop it from the original and not from the cropped file.

When I try adding an :original style to see if that works the original is cropped but then all the other images are basically blank.

How do I get a paperclip processor to apply the transformation to the original image and save it as well as the styles?